# Pandas handle textfile ending with separator

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a textfile with the separator ";".

```
"Age ";"AgeRange "
0;"000019";
1;"000019";
2;"000019";
3;"000019";
4;"000019";
5;"000019";
6;"000019";
7;"000019";
8;"000019";
9;"000019";
10;"000019";
11;"000019";
12;"000019";
13;"000019";
14;"000019";
15;"000019";
16;"000019";
17;"000019";
18;"000019";
19;"000019";
20;"020024";
```

When using pd.DataFrame with sep=";" I am getting columns Index(['Age ', 'AgeRange '], dtype='object').

```
    with open(f, "rb") as f:
        file_io_obj = BytesIO(f.read())

    if config['file_type'] == 'txt':
        fil:pd.DataFrame = pd.read_csv(file_io_obj, header=dataHeader, skipfooter=dataSkipFooter, dtype=str, sep=config['file_separator'])
```

But in my dataframe my rows have now also a NaN value.

```
  Age  AgeRange 
0  000019             NaN
1  000019             NaN
2  000019             NaN
3  000019             NaN
4  000019             NaN
```

I want the following DataFrame:

```
Age  AgeRange
0    000019
1    000019
2    000019
3    000019
4    000019
```

Same script will handle multiple files with the same setup:

```
"Inst ";"Year ";"WageType ";"Budget/consumption ";"consumption.type ";"consumption.type "
"DY";"2017";"_L_";"F";"90";"DY201790";
"DY";"2017";"000";"B";"01";"DY201701";
"DY";"2017";"000";"F";"01";"DY201701";
"DY";"2017";"005";"B";"01";"DY201701";
"DY";"2017";"005";"F";"01";"DY201701";
"DY";"2017";"006";"B";"01";"DY201701";
"DY";"2017";"006";"F";"01";"DY201701";
"DY";"2017";"008";"B";"01";"DY201701";
"DY";"2017";"008";"F";"01";"DY201701";
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Argument should be 'sep=', not 'spe=' as you wrote. Is this just a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('yourfile.txt', sep=';', dtype='str', usecols=[1])
```

Then if needed, rename your index:

```
data.index.set_names(['Age'], inplace=True)
```

And/or reset it:

```
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
    Age AgeRange
0   0   000019
1   1   000019
2   2   000019
3   3   000019
4   4   000019
```

Following your updated question, here's how to do it if you have several files:

```
usecols=[i for i in range(min, max)]
```

or

```
usecols=[*range(min, max)])
```

Comment: Hi John
Not quite unfortunately. I got the following result. Here I am missing the column for age
```
  AgeRange 
0          000019
1          000019
2          000019
3          000019
4          000019 ```

Comment: Was editing the answer. Did you try the updated one? They should produce your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but i need a more dynamic code. See updated description

Comment: Might be able to do `usecols=[i for i in range()]` with maximum number of columns in your files

Comment: Thanks John !
It worked with a range in usecols=[*range( x , x ) ]

Comment: Thanks, Mark Andersen. I updated my answer. If it works for you, can you please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('age.txt', sep=';', dtype='str', usecols=[0,1])
```

or

```
data = pd.read_csv('age.txt', sep=';', dtype='str', usecols=[0,1]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

which returns

```
   Age  AgeRange 
0     0    000019
1     1    000019
2     2    000019
3     3    000019
4     4    000019
5     5    000019
6     6    000019
7     7    000019
8     8    000019
9     9    000019
10   10    000019
11   11    000019
12   12    000019
13   13    000019
14   14    000019
15   15    000019
16   16    000019
17   17    000019
18   18    000019
19   19    000019
20   20    020024
```

Comment: Hi Serge
I need something more dynamic. I same script will also need to handle the following file:
` "Inst ";"Year ";"wagetype";"Budget/Consumption ";"Omk.type ";"Omk.type "
"DY";"2017";"_L_";"F";"90";"DY201790";
"DY";"2017";"000";"B";"01";"DY201701";
"DY";"2017";"000";"F";"01";"DY201701";
"DY";"2017";"005";"B";"01";"DY201701";
"DY";"2017";"005";"F";"01";"DY201701";
"DY";"2017";"006";"B";"01";"DY201701";
"DY";"2017";"006";"F";"01";"DY201701";`